# Simple Injector: Implementation that depends on http request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I'm a beginner with Simple Injector and have a scenario where I need help to implement. I will try to simplify what I need to do.

I have a WebAPI where I need to authenticate users and based on the type of user choose an implementation.

Consider this structure

```
public interface ICarRepository {
    void SaveCar(Car car);
}

//Some implementation for ICarRepository

public interface ICarLogic {
    void CreateCar(Car car);
}

public class CarLogicStandard: ICarLogic {
    private ICarRepository _carRepository;

    public CarLogicStandard(ICarRepository carRepository) {
        _carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    public void CreateCar(Car car) {
        car.Color = "Blue";
        _carRepository.SaveCar();
        //Other stuff...
    }
}

public class CarLogicPremium: ICarLogic {
    private ICarRepository _carRepository;

    public CarLogicPremium(ICarRepository carRepository) {
        _carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    public void CreateCar(Car car) {
        car.Color = "Red";
        _carRepository.SaveCar();
        //Other stuff 2...
    }

}
```

And now I have a controller

```
public class CarController: ApiController {
    private ICarLogic _carLogic;
    public CarController(ICarLogic carLogic) {
        _carLogic = carLogic;
    }

    public void Post(somePostData) {
        //Identify the user based on post data
        //....

        Car car = somePostData.SomeCar();
        _carLogic.CreateCar(car);
    }


}
```

The code above will not work because in my request I need to identify the user. If it is a premium user the controller should use the CarLogicPremium and if it is a standard user the controller should use the CarLogicStandard.

I can configure the repository and others interfaces that don't need this logic on  Global.asax however, since this case I need the request to decide which implementation should be used, I supose that I need to solve this in some other way.

There is a "Simple Injector" way to handle this? Or should I try another approach?

Comment: Why don't you use a factory to resolve the desired implementation of the `ICarLogic` interface? And to be honest, you shouldn't have 2 different implementations just because of the type of user, what if you end up adding more user types down the road?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. What you would recommend instead of interface implementation? You are right, more user types will exists and some of them will need to change the behavior of certain classes... Should I create a different interface for each different behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to configure the decision in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), along with the rest of the container's configuration:

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<CarLogicStandard>();
    container.Register<CarLogicPremium>();
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();
    container.Register<ICarLogic>(
        () =>
            HttpContext.Current != null &&
                HttpContext.Current.User != null &&
                HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Premium")
            ? (ICarLogic)container.GetInstance<CarLogicPremium>()
            : (ICarLogic)container.GetInstance<CarLogicStandard>()
        );

    // This is an extension method from the integration package.
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    container.Verify();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

You could also create an abstraction over the current user and decorate *standard* features with *premium* features

```cs
public class CarLogicPremium : ICarLogic
{
    private readonly ICarLogic decorated;
    private readonly ICurrentUser currentUser;
    private readonly ICarRepository carRepository;

    public CarLogicPremium(
        ICarLogic decorated,
        ICurrentUser currentUser,
        ICarRepository carRepository)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    public void CreateCar(Car car)
    {
        if (currentUser.IsPremiumMember)
        {
            car.Color = "Red";
            this.carRepository.SaveCar(car);
            //Other stuff 2...
        }
        else
        {
            this.decorated.CreateCar(car);
        }
    }
}
```

which would be configured a bit like this

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    var container = new Container();

    container.Register<ICurrentUser, HttpCurrentUserProxy>();
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();
    container.Register<ICarLogic, CarLogicStandard>();
    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICarLogic), typeof(CarLogicPremium));

    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    container.Verify();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

But it really depends how many variations of services you will be creating over time. If you will be constantly adding new premium features you should look to implement a variation of the *Try-X* pattern. Let me know if one of the above works for you or if you need more info ...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Great answer, however I had one problem at this line: (ICarLogic)container.GetInstance<CarLogicPremium>()


"The registered delegate for type CarLogicPremium threw an exception. Can't intercept type CarLogicPremium because it is not an interface."

Even registering CarLogicPremium this happened, do you know why?

Comment: @Rafael are you using the [interception extensions](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html)?

Comment: In general, my advice is to prevent making decisions over runtime data during object graph construction. I therefore not advice @qujck's first answer, but I agree with his second suggestion: use a facade/proxy/decorator that delegates through the right implementation.

Comment: @qujck Yes, I have the interception extension on my project. Is it causing the problem?

Comment: @Steven Thanks for your advice. I will try the decorator approach!

Comment: @Rafael yes the error is a within the interception code, raise another question if this is a real issue for you and we'll look into it

Comment: @qujck Yeah, I commented the interception and worked fine. Since it is just a example to practice I will investigate this issue later if it happens in a scenario that makes sense. Thank you very much for both solutions!